# Terminal freeze encountered when trying to avoid password prompt for serial port access using minicom

Tags: sudo, serial-port, usb-device, serial-console, minicom

I am trying to open the device `/dev/ttyUSB5` using `minicom`:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~$ sudo minicom -D /dev/ttyUSB5 -b 115200
```

The above throws the password prompt at the terminal when I run it. Before doing the above, I had made sure that I added the user to the `sudo` group by doing the following:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~$ sudo gpasswd -a user4 sudo
[sudo] password for user4: 
Adding user user4 to group sudo
```

I also added the following to `/etc/sudoers` file to ensure that `user4` doesn't get prompted for password in order to get access to the serial port `/dev/ttyUSB5` through `minicom` :

```
user4 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/bin/minicom
```

I was still getting the password prompt! Then, I tried adding `user4` to the `dialout` group and avoiding `sudo` altogether by doing the following:

```
user4@user-pc-4:~$ sudo gpasswd -a user4 dialout
[sudo] password for user4: 
Adding user user4 to group dialout
```

The above did the job alright, but `minicom` is unresponsive (terminal not responding to key inputs even though help menu is accessible by pressing down Ctrl+A-Z) now, though it seemed to have gained access to `/dev/ttyUSB5` without any password prompt.

What is going wrong here? How can I disable the password prompt for a specific program without giving the user a complete privilege? I have a feeling I'm missing some piece of information - either with `/etc/sudoers` or with `/dev/ttyUSB5`.